# Rails rspec undefined local variable or method `render_views'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When running the rspec I get:

> C:/www/kill/spec/games_controller_spec.rb:4:in `block in <top
>   (required)>': undefined local variable or method`render_views'

### games_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe GamesController, "creating a new game" do
  render_views
  fixtures :games

  it "should redirect to index with a notice on successful save" do
    Game.any_instance.stubs(:valid?).returns(true)
    post 'create'
    assigns[:game].should_not be_new_record
    flash[:notice].should_not be_nil
    response.should redirect_to(menu_items_path)
  end
end
```

### spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # == Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  #config.mock_with :rspec

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
end
```

### gems:

> C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-2.7.0
>
> C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mocha-0.10.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should place your controller specs inside a `spec/controllers` directory. RSpec is including these methods based on this, AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you, that was my problem.

Answer (score 17):

Your controller specs should be in the `spec/controllers/` folder. However, you may want for some reason to have some other files that run controller specs (for example, I'm testing markup validation in a separate test file).

You can do this :

```
describe GamesController, "creating a new game", :type => :controller do
```

And this should do the trick !

Comment: For me, an additional problem was that I didn't "require 'rspec/rails'" in the spec_helper.rb ...

Comment: This worked for me. After upgrading rspec, I need to add the `type: :controller` to the describe block even though it was in the correct directory structure. go figure...

Comment: Please note that the `require 'spec_helper'` syntax is deprecated since RSpec 3.0 and has been replaced by `require 'rails_helper'` (thus you have to rename the corresponding file).

Comment: I had a similar issue with `spec/views/...` and the solution as @FabriceCarrega mentioned, change `spec_helper` to `rails_helper`. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In my case my test was already in `spec/controllers/`. I needed to add `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` inside the `RSpec.configure do |config|` loop in spec_helper.rb. I had updated rspec from 2.x to 3.x without realizing it, and that config is needed for controller tests from 3.x.

Answer (score 3):

If you test the views, RSpec have the `spec/requests` directory for that, it will render views by default. ([See the doc](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec))

Answer (score 0):

this problem may be caused by your Gem rspec-rails version. downgrade it back to 2.x solved my problem:

```
# edit your Gemfile
gem "rspec-rails", "2.14.2"
```